# Can we check if the file exists or not in Azure SQL?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to find an alternative for master.dbo.xp_fileexist. It works fine in SQL Server but it doesn't work in Azure SQL database. Does this command support or any other alternative is there?

Comment: are you using SQL as service?

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database is a PaaS product and you cannot use extended stored procedures to access the file system with Azure SQL Database.

With PaaS products you use Azure Storage Account or One Drive to store files and use [Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage) to trigger processing of those files. [Here](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip40.html) is an example of Logic Apps processing files on OneDrive. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage#add-trigger) is an example of Logic Apps processing files arriving on a storage account.

An Azure Logic Apps can be triggered to process files when they arrive or when they are modified, for example.

[image]

After that you specify what action will be executed.

[image]

[image]